# mysql update 2 blobs at once not working

Tags: mysql, image, upload, blob

i'm having an issue when trying to update two BLOB fields in a row using mysql and php commands.

Inserting the BLOBs into the row seems to work no problem, here is what I do.

```
$logotemp = $_FILES['eventlogo']['tmp_name'];
$thumbnailtemp = $_FILES['eventthumbnail']['tmp_name'];
$openlogo      = fopen($logotemp, 'r');
$openthumbnail      = fopen($thumbnailtemp, 'r');
$logo = fread($openlogo, filesize($logotemp));
$logo = addslashes($logo);
$thumbnail = fread($openthumbnail, filesize($thumbnailtemp));
$thumbnail = addslashes($thumbnail);
fclose($openlogo);
fclose($openthumbnail);
```

So I have two form file inputs, and those files are read, and then set as the variables $log and $thumbnail. I then use the following command to enter this into the DB:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO $table (`Event Logo`, `Venue Logo`) VALUES ('$logo', '$thumbnail')";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if(!$result) {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

The above works fine, although I have trimmed out the rest of the fields that also get filled. The query works, and I can return the images to a page, and then display them along with all of the other information from that row.

I then want to edit the row, so created a new php file called edit.php, which is a copy of the php file used above, called new.php.

This means that the form is identical, and when the page is displayed, the value for each input is prefilled with the info from the database, the logo and thumbnail are shown next to the upload fields.

If I then run a query to update the row, using almost the same code as above, it always enteres an empty value into both blobs, essentially deleting the uploaded images. Here is what happens:

```
    $id = $_POST['eventid'];        
    $logotemp = $_FILES['eventlogo']['tmp_name'];
    $openlogo      = fopen($logotemp, 'r');
    $logo = fread($openlogo, filesize($logotemp));
    $thumbnailtemp = $_FILES['eventthumbnail']['tmp_name'];
    $openthumbnail      = fopen($thumbnailtemp, 'r');
    $thumbnail = fread($openthumbnail, filesize($thumbnailtemp));
    fclose($openlogo);
    fclose($openthumbnail);
```

So once again, the form fields are still called eventlogo and eventthumbnail, and the variables are still $logo and $thumbnail. I then use the following query to update the row:

```
$qry = "UPDATE $table SET `Event Name` = '$name', `Date` = '$date', `Time` = '$time', `Venue` = '$venue', `Price` = '$price', `Open To` = '$opento', `Rep Name` = '$repname', `Rep Email` = '$repemail', `Address` = '$address', `Website` = '$website', `Phone` = '$phone', `Description` = '$description', `Event Logo` = '$logo', `Venue Logo` = '$thumbnail' WHERE `Event ID` = '$id'";
```

I have left in the other variables that are updated this time.

```
$result = mysql_query($qry);
if(!$result) {
die(mysql_error());
}
```

When the query runs, it will update any other fields I want, except for the two image BLOB fields at the end. Considering I copied and pasted the code for the upload fields, the code to read the contents of that field, and then manually typed out a query to update those fields, I can't see what's going wrong.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Eds

Comment: 1st. Use parametrized SQL, as-is, this is inviting trouble. Second, in the edit.php you're missing 'addslashes' call over logo, at least. Binary data will include characters that mess up your sql query, but mysql (and other sql servers) will silently accept those.

Comment: Sorry, my code does include the addslashes, but didnt include them here for some reason. It must be something wrong in the opening of the file and reading it as binary, and just coming up empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant find the code I sorted this with, but I think I ended up just updating one at a time.